# Replace CRLF in file

Tags: powershell

I am actually trying to make a .txt file looking like this:

```
text1
text 2


text3
text4
```

in something like this:

```
text1,text2
text3,text4
```

I have tried a lot of things, like:

```
foreach($line in $file){
    $line=$line -replace'`r`n', ','
}
```

Or directly by replacing in the file and not the string:

```
$file=Get-Content('testo.txt')
$file=$file -replace '`r`n',''
```

But nothing worked. I have never been able to replace the CRLF.
If someone has an idea or anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something even simpler I think. This would depend on the size of the text file since it has to be all read into memory. However this would will work with variable lines of "test" data and white space. I am going to *assume* that your data does not already contain commas.

```powershell
$file = (Get-Content "c:\temp\data.txt") -join "," -replace ",{2,}","`r`n"
Set-Content -Path "C:\temp\Newfile.txt" -Value $file
```

Take the file and convert it into a comma delimited string. What will happen is that you will see a series of groups commas. Using your test data

```
text1,text 2,,,text3,text4
```

The we use regex to replace and consecutive comma groups of 2 or more with newlines. Getting the desired output.

```
text1,text 2
text3,text4
```

Comment: More concise than mine and it works (maybe better ;p )

Comment: If there is something wrong with this it would be nice to know why it was downvoted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact i have done something like this:

```
$Writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter "$($PWD.Path)\$OutputFile"
$Writer.Write( [String]::Join(".", $data) )
$Writer.Close()
$data=get-content temp.txt
$data=$data -replace '[@]{2,}',"`r`n"
$data=$data -replace '[@]',","
$data=$data -replace '(&nbsp;){1,},',"no data"
$data>>temp1.txt
```

It works and do what I want. It is not exactly efficient, but I wanted it to work quickly.
I will try all the answers when I have the time and say if it works or not.
And maybe I will change this part of my script if I find something more efficient.
Thanks to all!

Comment: I would think this solution would have an issue with consecutive characters in you actual data since you are matching _any_ character with the `.`

Comment: Yes I had an error some hours ago, and modified the dot by an "@" which will never been in the document I need to work with.
In fact I needed to make a .csv from an html report with tags about server backup.

Comment: Ok... now this answer is confusing since its does not match the sample data of your question. Did you have a look at the other answers? I wonder now if they will not work since your actual data might not look like that.